# Resolver Issue for @extends Type in GraphQL Apollo Federation-JVM

Tags: java, graphql, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

I am quite new to Apollo Federation and Gateway and trying to use [apollo federation-jvm](https://github.com/apollographql/federation-jvm) for a demo project. I have created two federated services using federation jvm. Both these services are connected to each other via Apollo Gateway. Using [this](https://github.com/apollographql/federation-demo) node gateway example from their official github page.

Below is the schema and resolvers for these services:

Federated Service 1:

video.graphql

```
type Video @key(fields: "videoId") {
    videoId: String!
    description: String
    relatedNameId: String
}

type Query {
    topVideo: Video
    allVideos: [Video]
}
```

Resolvers for video.graphql

```
@Service
public class VideoQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private static final List<Video> videos = Lists.newArrayList(
            Video.builder().videoId("vi00000001").description("Video 1").relatedNameId("nm000001").build(),
            Video.builder().videoId("vi00000002").description("Video 2").relatedNameId("nm000001").build()
    );

    public Video topVideo() {
        return videos.get(0);
    }

    public List<Video> allVideos() {
        return videos;
    }
}
```

Federated service 2:

name.graphql

```
type Name @key(fields: "nameId") {
    nameId: String!
    displayName: String
}

type Query {
    getByNameId(nameId: String): Name
    getAllNames: [Name]
}
```

Resolvers for name.graphql

```
@Service
public class NameQuery implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private static final List<Name> names = Lists.newArrayList(
            Name.builder().nameId("nm0000001").displayName("Pam Beesley").build(),
            Name.builder().nameId("nm0000002").displayName("Dwight Schrute").build(),
            Name.builder().nameId("nm0000003").displayName("Michael Scott").build()
    );

    public Name getByNameId(final String nameId) {
        final Optional<Name> oName = names.stream().filter(name -> name.getNameId().equalsIgnoreCase(nameId))
                                     .findFirst();
        return oName.orElse(null);
    }

    public List<Name> getAllNames(final DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) {
        return names;
    }

}
```

I am able to call all the API's (topVideo, allVideos, getByNameId, getAllNames) in Type Query of both the services **via gateway** without any issues.

However when I extend the **Name** Type in **Video** Type schema by adding the following to the video.graphql schema

```
type Name @key(fields: "nameId") @extends {
    nameId: String! @external
    getVideoByNameId: [Video]
}
```

I am not sure how to write the resolver for **getVideoByNameId** field.

I have tried adding  method  **getVideoByNameId(String nameId)** to VideoQuery.java (returning hardcoded video object from getVideoByNameId method) but the graph always returns null.

I have also tried to create RuntimeWiring using below code and then passing that when creating GraphQLSchema object as shown in an example on their [github page](https://github.com/apollographql/federation-jvm/blob/master/spring-example/src/main/java/com/apollographql/federation/springexample/InventorySchemaProvider.java#L23)

```
private static RuntimeWiring getRuntimeWiring(){
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                            .type(newTypeWiring("Name")
                                                  .dataFetcher("getVideoByNameId", new StaticDataFetcher(someVideo)))
                            .type(newTypeWiring("Query")
                                                  .dataFetcher("topVideo", new StaticDataFetcher(someVideo)))
                            .type(newTypeWiring("Query")
                                                  .dataFetcher("allVideos", new StaticDataFetcher(someVideo)))
                            .build();
    }
```

Nothing seems to work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to implement `fetchEntities` and `resolveEntityType` for your `Name` type similarly to the way they are implemented [here](https://github.com/apollographql/federation-jvm/blob/master/spring-example/src/main/java/com/apollographql/federation/springexample/InventorySchemaProvider.java#L23).